# How to select sum of column in result of select?

Tags: mysql

How to select sum of column in result of select?

Comment: This is realy badly stated. Could you possibly show input/output or actualy explain what you require?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) is a list of MySQL built in functions for the group by aggregate

> ```
> AVG() Return the average value of the argument
> BIT_AND() Return bitwise and
> BIT_OR()  Return bitwise or
> BIT_XOR()(v4.1.1) Return bitwise xor
> COUNT(DISTINCT)   Return the count of a number of different values
> COUNT()   Return a count of the number of rows returned
> GROUP_CONCAT()(v4.1)  Return a concatenated string
> MAX() Return the maximum value
> MIN() Return the minimum value
> STD() Return the population standard deviation
> STDDEV_POP()(v5.0.3)  Return the population standard deviation
> STDDEV_SAMP()(v5.0.3) Return the sample standard deviation
> STDDEV()  Return the population standard deviation
> SUM() Return the sum
> VAR_POP()(v5.0.3) Return the population standard variance
> VAR_SAMP()(v5.0.3)    Return the sample variance
> VARIANCE()(v4.1)  Return the population standard variance
> ```

I believe that you want `SUM()`

Answer (score 17):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(your_column) AS Total
FROM
    your_table;
```

... or is this a trick question? :)

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT SUM(sales) as "Revenue" FROM details;`

Answer (score 1):

SELECT SUM(col) FROM table

Comment: This will never work, grouping by the col you are aggregating?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(`subquery`.`qty`) FROM (
SELECT `qty` FROM `table1` WHERE [ your query conditions ]
) AS `subquery`
```

Comment: this can be used when you need distinct on multiple columns and use group by  as well. 
if you need to find total unique checkouts of books then...
example :
SELECT SUM(`subquery`.`total`) FROM (
select count(distinct(user_id)) as total  from checkout group by book_id
) AS `subquery`