# PHP Calculate Total Views

Tags: php, sql

i have a table with a lots of articles, each article have number of views.
how i can calculate all the views?

Table Example:

```
-----------------------------
id | title | content | views
-----------------------------
1 | name | thecontent | 15
2 | name | thecontent | 22
3 | name | thecontent | 6
4 | name | thecontent | 49
```

total views: 92

thank you.

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select sum of column in result of select?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280680/how-to-select-sum-of-column-in-result-of-select)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;<br>
```

PHP:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes'); <br>
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); <br>
$sum = $row['value_sum'];<br>
```

Comment: Thank you for the extended code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SUM()`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp) function.

Try this query...

```
SELECT SUM(views) as total_views FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(views) AS views FROM <table name>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using MySQL's `SUM()` function.

```
SELECT SUM(views) as num_views FROM TBL_NAME
```